# Установка Sass в React проект

Tags: reactjs, sass, scss, node-sass

Хочу установит `node-sass` в React проект, но вылазит такая ошибка  `Module build failed: TypeError: this.getResolve is not a function` Я пробовал много чего, но ничего не помогает. Удалил `node_modules` и `package-lock.json` и запустил `npm install`, установил все лоадеры ( css, sass, style), добавил зависимость в файле `webpack.config.dev.js`, но, ничего не помогает.

[Файл webpack.config.dev.js](https://jsfiddle.net/sytrvbj3/)

Comment: Установи с нуля новый проект используя `create-react-app` и попробуй там.

Comment: Не смогу, проект рабочий

Comment: Посмотрел тут  https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/761 ?

Comment: Да, смотрел, поднял версию webpack до 4.36.0 но теперь проект не запускается пишет такую ошибку "   this.compiler.applyPluginsAsync is not a function "